Как сделать красную линию поверх другой?

Как сделать красную линию поверх другой линии при клике на "Статистика"?
Искал информацию, можно как-то реализовать через border-bottom

Для активной ссылки задайте активный класс, например .active-link.
.active-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

